# Merge or Concatenate Multiple files into 1 file in GCS using Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to recreate this script that will merge csv files that have same schema in the gcs into 1 csv file but i couldnt make it work. I keep getting error.

I have 3 files namely, position1.csv, position2.csv, position3.csv and my bucket name is gatest with subfolder Extract.

Error message:
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
'name'

```
import google.cloud.storage.client as gcs
import logging


def compose_shards(data, context):

    num_shards = 3

    prefix = 'Extract/position' 
    outfile = 'Extract/full_position_data.csv'
    filename = data['name']    #keep getting error here with only 'name', what should be the expected value here? 
    last_shard = '-%05d-of-%05d' % (num_shards - 1, num_shards)
    if (prefix in filename and last_shard in filename):
        prefix = filename.replace(last_shard,'')
        client = gcs.Client()
        bucket = client.bucket(data['bucket']) #i tried replacing bucket with my gcs bucket name but it didnt work, also having error here
        blobs = []
    for shard in range (num_shards):
        sfile = '%s-%05d-of-%05d' % (prefix, shard + 1, num_shards)
        blob = bucket.blob(sfile)
        if not blob.exists():
            raise ValueError('Shard {} not present'.format(sfile))
        blobs.append(blob)

    bucket.blob(outfile).compose(blobs)
    logging.info('Successfully created {}'.format(outfile))
    for blob in blobs:
        blob.delete()
    logging.info('Deleted {} shards'.format(len(blobs)))
```

Comment: Hey, I think you we're following this guide[1]. This guide was made to interact with dataflow data. Try printing the data value and see what it contains.  What information are you getting in the logs of the function? 

[1]: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-write-to-a-single-shard-on-google-cloud-storage-efficiently-using-cloud-dataflow-and-cloud-3aeef1732325

Comment: I got the same error. I missed the dataflow part, since I already have the files i want to merge in GCS. @Stefan G

Comment: Can you please attempt to print data and see what data it contains or what you are recovering in order to see if it's being recovered correctly? Can you also check the logs to see if we have any further information about the error?